# How to let imported css font / icons have effects on elements in the shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, html5-template

Say if I want to create a custom element using shadow dom. Some elements in the template have class names specified in the linked css file. Now I want to let the css rules have effects on the elements. But I can't achieve that because of the shadow dom style boundary.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<template id="blog-header">
<header>
    <h1>DreamLine</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#0">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Error</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
        value: function () {
            var t = importDoc.querySelector("#blog-header");
            var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
            this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
});
document.registerElement("blog-header", {
    prototype: proto
});
</script>
```

You see, `fa-search` is a class defined in the font-awesome css file, how can I style the `<i>` element?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To use an imported font (e.g., *FontAwesome*) in a Shadow DOM, you should:

**1° Declare the Font**

First, include the `<link rel="stylesheet">` element in the main document. It will declare a `@font-face` CSS rule that will make the font available for all the text in the document.

**2° Import the Stylesheet**

Then, import  the same file with an `@import url` CSS rule  in the `<template>` node to make the `.fa-*` classes selectors available from the Shadow DOM :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<template id="blog-header">
  <style>
    @import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css")
  </style>
  <header>
    <h1>DreamLine</h1>
    //...
  </header>
</template>
```

```js
var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
 createdCallback: {
  value: function() {
   var t = importDoc.querySelector("#blog-header");
   var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
   this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
  }
 }
});
document.registerElement("blog-header", {prototype: proto});
```

```css
/* 
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0") format('woff2');
  }
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<template id="blog-header">
  <style>
    @import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css")
  </style>
 <header>
  <h1>DreamLine</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#0">Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Error</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</template>

<blog-header></blog-header>
```

**Update 2019**

Now you can use `<link rel="stylesheet">` instead of `@import url()` inside a Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I had imported a sample project which had mdi icons, in to a bigger project as submodule. My sample project uses mdi icons inside leaflet map which were not getting downloaded when map image was being downloaded in bigger project with dom-to-image package.
The way I had to add it in a vue file to make it work is as follows:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.6.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```