# Global CSS for an app with web components

Tags: css, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm developing a web application that uses HTML 5 native web components. My problem is that I have a lot of common CSS  for all of these and I use font awesome to have nice icons. Right now I put all my styles inside "/deep" shadow piercing but Chrome says : "/deep/ combinator is deprecated." Do you have any suggestions on how can I have global CSS and CSS libraries (like font awesome) available on the whole app ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could include the CSS font file globally, with the `<link rel="stylesheet">` element.

Then, you'll have to import it locally in every Custom Element's `<template>`, in a `<style>` element, using the `@import url` CSS rule.

There's a running example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35879636/4600982).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think indeed that this is the cleaner solution. I didn't wanted to do it because I need to include it in all my components.