# chrome extension shadow DOM import boostrap fonts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, font-face, shadow-dom

so I'd like to display bootstrap 3 icons in a shadowroot added from a chrome extension content script. So far its not working, help?

manifest.js does include the woff file in web_accessible_resources

shadow root has style tag with:

```
 @import url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To import a font, you should not use `@import url` which is used to import a CSS stylesheet.

Instead, you should use the [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) directive.

Also, this directive should be placed in the `<head>` element of the HTML page, not inside the Shadow DOM.

```js
host.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = `
    <style>.icon { font-family: Icons; color: green ; font-size:30pt }</style>
    <span class="icon">&#xe084</span>`
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Icons" ;
    src: url("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2")
}
```

```html
<div id=host></div>
```

You can read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35879636/4600982) for further details.