# How to use Material Design Icons in a web component?

Tags: web-component, native-web-component, css-import, material-design-icons

Looks like that mdi is not working inside web components, or do I miss something?

I want to develop a web component that encapsulates it's dependencies, adding the link to the parent document works, but it violates the original intent.

```
<html>
<body>
<x-webcomponent></x-webcomponent>
<script>
customElements.define(
  "x-webcomponent",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>@import url('https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css');</style>
        <span class="mdi mdi-home"></span>
      `;
    }
  }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/Jamesgt/pen/MWwvJaw

Comment: Looks like that css `@import` is not working and I guess because it refers other resources also...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let imported css have effects on elements in the shadow dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858494/how-to-let-imported-css-have-effects-on-elements-in-the-shadow-dom)

Comment: add the <link> in the main document, too

Comment: Thanks, edited the question, `<link>` in outer doc helps, but I don't feel it an elegant solution.

Comment: maybe it seems inelegant but it's the only solution using font by now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@font-face` CSS at-rule for the font you want to use must be declared in the main document, not in the Shadow DOM.

Because in your case it is defined in the *materialdesignicons.min.css* file, you'll need to load it in the main document via a global `<link>`.

Note that the CSS file won't be loaded twice thanks to the browser's cache.

Alternately, you could add it in the light DOM of the web component, or you could just declare the `@font-face` at-rule (copied from the *materialdesignicons.css* file).

Here is a running example:

```js
customElements.define( "x-webcomponent", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <link rel=stylesheet  href=https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css>
        <span class="mdi mdi-home"></span>`
    }
    connectedCallback () {
      this.innerHTML = `<style>
          @font-face {
            font-family: "Material Design Icons";
            src: url("https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff?v=4.9.95") format("woff");
          }
       </style>`
    }
} )
```

```html
<x-webcomponent></x-webcomponent>
```

Comment: note that in the snippet example I've added only the font that work for Firefox and Chrome on Windows. Maybe you'll need to add another font format for Safari and/or Apple / Linux

Comment: note also that putting `font-face`or `link`in the light DOM will be redundant if you insert multiple instances of the custom element in the same page/iframe